# WEB API+ MVC | I am trying to make a simple login form but its not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

myconroller

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(ProfileView modelo)
    {
        
        List<ProfileView> modelList = new List<ProfileView>();
        
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + "api/employee").Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            modelList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProfileView>>(data);

           foreach(var modelos in modelList)
            {
               if(modelos.Email == modelo.Email & modelos.Password == modelo.Password)
                {
                    
                    return View("Register");
                }
            }
        }
        return View("Login");


    }
```

my view

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Profile", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)
    <div class="form-group">
        <div lass="container-login100-form-btn">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="login100-form-btn" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

i don't understand why it's the part in my controller where in the if statement is  going false, the if statement inside the foreach.

Comment: Why don't you use `ASP.NEt Identity`? and also are you sure password in `modelList` is not hash?

Comment: i don't think it will conaint any hash because webapi only returns either xml or json, i am new to this, i dont know how to use that identity but will do my research on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this simple login approach which uses `ASP.NET Identity` it might be useful for you.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]

    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsNotValid())
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Blog");

        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Account is locked out.");
            return View(model);
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Login Failed. UserName or Password is incorrect");
        return View(model);
    }
```

`LoginViewModel` is  :

```
 public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

`_signInManager` is injected in the constructor like this :

```
 private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

    public SecurityController(SignInManager<User> signInManager, UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

and also in the `startup.cs` I have this setting :

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Security/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Security/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Security/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Name = ".Freetime",
                Path = "/",
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest
            };
        });
```